# How could i set coockies in JS ,expiring of values in input fields?

Tags: javascript, cookies

if someone would offer me some help about setting cookies and how would I use the most simple coding to do that and also the how they would expire. I had a similar question previous about sessionStorage and learned to do that. the code that I'm using is just a simple input of  a name, as a starter to figure out how the logic works around them. thank you in advanced for the help.

```
<input type="text" id="name" ><br><br>
<input type="submit" value="set coockie" id="btn">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like done below

```
<input type="text" id="name" ><br><br>
<input type="submit" value="set coockie" id="btn" onclick="setCookie()" >


function setCookie(){

const cookieValue = document.getElementById("name").value
document.cookie = `cookieName=${cookieValue}; max-age=86400; path=/;`;

}
```